# i18n special characters not displaying correctly in thymeleaf email template

Tags: html, internationalization, thymeleaf, special-characters

I'm using i18n to translate emails in my Java SpringBoot Application, using thymeleaf as its templates. The problem occurs when i write special characters from portuguese language, when i receive the email (via Outlook web/app, and the Mail app from windows) it displays like this:

> Descri��o
> Para maiores informa��es clique aqui.

When I'm trying to display this text:

> Para maiores informações, clique aqui

> Descrição

I've tried with `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`, I've also tried adding HTML special characters to replace the C and A in portuguese like so: `descri&Ccedil&Atildeo` and it still doesnt work. I've done my research but I still cant find why these special characters wont display correctly.

Comment: Do you have your character encoding set on your template resolver?

Comment: hey! yes i do. its CharEncoding.UTF_8

Answer (score 1):

check the encoding of your thymeleaf template file (<your_template>.html) in your IDE. this should also be UTF-8. In some cases (like e.g. messages.properties) the default is ISO-8859-1